# Android's RGBToHSV method doesn't work

Tags: android

According to [the document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#RGBToHSV%28int,%20int,%20int,%20float%5b%5d%29), android.graphics.Color has a method called `RGBToHSV` which can convert RGB values to HSV, this is what the document tells me:

```
public static void RGBToHSV (int red, int green, int blue, float[] hsv)
```

> #### Convert RGB components to HSV.
>
> - `hsv[0]` is Hue [0 .. 360)
> - `hsv[1]` is Saturation [0...1]
> - `hsv[2]` is Value [0...1]
>
> #### Parameters
>
> - *red*:  red component value [0..255]
> - *green*:    green component value [0..255]
> - *blue*: blue component value [0..255]
> - *hsv*:  3 element array which holds the resulting HSV components.

But when I write a program to test it, it doesn't work any way.

```
float[] hsv = new float[3];

RGBToHSV(255, 255, 0, hsv);

Log.i("HSV_H", "" + hsv[0]);   // always output 0.0
```

Is it a bug ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are your expected values? To me it seems to be working.

The code I used:

```
float[] hsv = new float[3];
android.graphics.Color.RGBToHSV(255, 255, 0, hsv);
Log.i("HSV_H", "Hue=" + hsv[0]);
Log.i("HSV_H", "Saturation=" + hsv[1]);
Log.i("HSV_H", "Value=" + hsv[2]);
```

The results:

```
Hue=60.0
Saturation=1.0
Value=1.0
```

This was run using a project targeting Android SDK 1.6 (API level 4) on a 1.6 emulator.

Answer (score 1):

The result for hsv[1], hsv [2] is a decimal number, so you have to multiply by 100 to get the percentage.

Answer (score 0):

There is no indication that RGBtoHSV is assigning any values to the hsv array; try something like this:

```
RGBtoHSV(255, 255, 0, hsv);
```

And then check the value of hsv[0].

Comment: public static **void** RGBToHSV()  I think this method will return nothing

Comment: Check my answer again; I failed to read the method definition when I posted my answer.